# Dynamic opdate icon chrome extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, google-chrome-extension

There angular script that sends the request. Get the answer in the form json. How to send your inquiry to periodically?
How to use an app icon image, located on the Internet, the data on which the receipt of zhson?`

```js
var app = angular.module('jsbin', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($http,$scope) {
  var vm = this;
   var temp1=[];
var URL2=[];
  var URL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily';
var showSwitch=false;
  var request = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: URL,
    params: {
       q: localStorage["var"],
      mode: 'json',
      units: localStorage["SystemOfNumbers"],
      cnt: '7',
      appid: '3ac1f68b653ffbf72a5f782420062771'
    }
  };
var showMe=false;



   $scope.myFunc=function() {
       $scope.showMe=!$scope.showMe;
           }


           var range = [];
           for(var i=0;i<7;i++) {
             range.push(i);
           }
           $scope.range = range;


           $scope.colorFont=function(templiche){
            if (templiche>0) return 'red';
             else {
               return 'blue';
             }
       }


 $http(request)
    .then(function(response) {
   vm.data = response.data;
   vm.URL2="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+vm.data.list[0].weather[0].icon+".png";
     vm.mmrts=Math.round(vm.data.list[0].pressure* 0.7500);
    vm.symbal=localStorage["Symbal"];


       }).
    catch(function(response) {
      vm.data = response.data;
      vm.URL2="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+vm.data.list[0].weather[0].icon+".png";
    vm.symbal=localStorage["Symbal"];
    });

}

);
```

```html
{
 "manifest_version" : 2,
 "name" : "...",
 "short_name" : "...",
 "version" : "1.0",
 "author" : "...",
 "description" : "...",

 "icons" : {
  "16" : "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/13d.png",
  "32" : "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/13d.png",
  "48" : "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/13d.png",
  "64" : "icons/64x64.png",
  "128" : "icons/128x128.png"
 },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
      "js": [ "weather.js" ]
    }
  ],

 "background" : {

 },
 "permissions": [
          "storage","activeTab"
        ],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "...",
        "default_icon": "icons/water.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

And format address icon:"http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{{item.weather[0].icon}}.png"

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically change icon with [setIcon method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setIcon). For example:

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:'https://example.com/image.png'});
```

To send request periodically, you need to create a [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) and use the [alarm API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms).